# How to prevent default action for kendogrid tool bar add button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendoGrid with toolbar add button. on Click of 'Add new record' button, a kendo pop up will be displayed to enter new record values (this is default behavior). 
If the Kendo grid contains atleast one rowI want to show an error message on click of 'Add new Record' button, .

Below code is what I have tried on document load, but it isn't working. Still the default behavior of the button persists.

```
     $('#k-grid-ID').kendoButton({
        click: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var locGrid = $('#locGrid0').data('kendoGrid');
            if (locGrid && locGrid.dataSource.data().length > 0) {
                var win = $('#ErrorWindow').data('kendoWindow');
                win.content('This Grid can contain only one record');
                win.open().center();
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using below appraoch.

```
$('#k-grid-ID').click(function (event) { return checkCount(event); });

function checkLocationsForEndo1056(e) {
    var locGrid = $('#locGrid0').data('kendoGrid');
    if (locGrid && locGrid.dataSource.data().length > 0) {
        var win = $('#ErrorWindow').data('kendoWindow');
        win.open().center();
        $('#endoGridErrorMsg').html('This Grid can contain only one record');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Still, not sure why the first approach didn't work